# I could not run the jhipster in browser, if intellijidea console shows Application running successfully

Tags: jhipster

[Project Link](https://github.com/GokulRamasamy/jhipster.git)

I mentioned application installed cmds, IntelliJ Idea console and output of the project from browser files are
1. Terminal cmds : https://github.com/GokulRamasamy/jhipster/blob/master/terminal%20code%20for%20jhipster
2. intellij console: https://github.com/GokulRamasamy/jhipster/blob/master/intellij%20console%20for%20jhipster
3. Browser Screenshot: https://github.com/GokulRamasamy/jhipster/blob/master/Screenshot%20from%202018-03-16%2018-08-12.png

Could you please explain why I got this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the required dependencies for JHipster AngularJS projects [as described in the docs](https://www.jhipster.tech/installation/#quick-setup-when-using-angularjs-1x).

Based on your generation log, you are missing `gulp` which can be fixed by running `yarn global add gulp-cli`

```
[17:48:09] Local gulp not found in ~/gokul/test/jhip1
[17:48:09] Try running: npm install gulp
```

The browser screenshot shows the steps you need to take to fix your generated project.  First, install the missing dependencies (gulp).  Then run the following commands:

```
yarn install
bower install
gulp install
```

This will build your frontend and inject bower dependencies into your index.html.  After this you should be able to see your JHipster frontend in the browser at http://localhost:8080

You can also rerun `jhipster --force --with-entities` to rerun JHipster which should rebuild the project correctly (once gulp is installed)

Comment: Thank you so much. I installed gulp and bower using yarn its works fine.   When i use "Local installation with NPM (alternative to Yarn)" it is not work properly. Once Thank you so much